# Compressing files in a folder using tar

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a loop which should compress all files in the current directory into a tar file.

There's an if statement to check if the tar file already exists and if so append files onto it.

```
FILE_NAME_ARCHIVE=sjohal_Jan_archive.tar

cd  /archive/sjohal/Jan

for file in `/bin/ls -1`
do  
 if [ -f $FILE_NAME_ARCHIVE ]
  then
    tar -cuf $FILE_NAME_ARCHIVE $file
 else
    tar -ruf $FILE_NAME_ARCHIVE $file
 fi
done
```

But for some reason I get the error 
    "tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' option"

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: `tar` is not a compressed format.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `-cuf` and `-ruf` but, as that error message makes clear, you can't use more than one of `-c`, `-r` and `-u` at once.

That being said you don't need to do any of this. `tar` should be fine creating a tar file that doesn't exist when using `-r` or `-u` so you can avoid the check entirely.

Also note that `-u` will duplicate the file in the tarball so the tarball will grow by the size of the updated file (it does not remove the old file).